# How to add dependency between operations like NSOperationQueue in GCD

Tags: ios, swift

Below are the 4 operations witch loads 4 images using NSOperation queue. Here operation2 is dependent on operation1 and operation3 depends on operation2.

Does anyone know I can we achieve same thing in GCD?

```
@IBAction func didClickOnStart(sender: AnyObject) {

        queue = NSOperationQueue()
        let operation1 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
            let img1 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[0])
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
                self.imageView1.image = img1
            })
        })

        operation1.completionBlock = {
            print("Operation 1 completed")
        }
        queue.addOperation(operation1)

        let operation2 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
            let img2 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[1])
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
                self.imageView2.image = img2
            })
        })

        operation2.completionBlock = {
            print("Operation 2 completed")
        }
        queue.addOperation(operation2)


        let operation3 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
            let img3 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[2])
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
                self.imageView3.image = img3
            })
        })

        operation3.completionBlock = {
            print("Operation 3 completed")
        }
        queue.addOperation(operation3)

        let operation4 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
            let img4 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[3])
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
                self.imageView4.image = img4
            })
        })

        operation4.completionBlock = {
            print("Operation 4 completed")
        }
        queue.addOperation(operation4)
    }
```

Here We can add dependencies between operation

```
operation2.addDependency(operation1)
operation3.addDependency(operation2)
```

Comment: What did you try to achieve the same thing in `GCD`?

Comment: @Fabian :- I tried using completion handler but I am not sure , it that a correct way or not.

Comment: If it does the thing you expect it to then it is correct by definition. Whether it is worth the resources to reimplement operations(which are built ontop GCD) is for you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

You can't(or just don't because it's much more work than using `OperationQueue` and `Operation` subclasses).